# Using VBA to click on Javascript drop down

Tags: vba, web-scraping, drop-down-menu, onclick, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to figure out how to navigate through a JS dropdown menu with VBA. I have went through so many forum posts but I just cannot seem to figure this out. In the below website code the option I am trying to select is highlighted "All Open Orders In View". I would really appreciate any guidance.

Here is the website code:
[image: JS Code]

Here is the VBA code that errors "Subscript out of Range":

```
    .document.getelementbyid("Main_Main_mbMain_5")().Click
    .FireEvent "onclick"
```

Thank you for any thoughts or help. Let me know if the full code is needed but the website is sadly not public.

*Edit
Here is a picture of the menu bar in question (without the reference and with the reference below)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `.document.getelementbyid("Main_Main_mbMain_5").Click` since getElementById only returns a single element (assuming a match), not an array/nodelist   You're just clicking the parent div though, and it's not clear that has any event handler attached.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Its actually that line that errors out with the "Subscript out of range". I added the "Onclick" thinking that it was not actually initializing the "All Open Orders In View" after it went through the first drop down, which I assumed was "Main_Main_mbMain_5".

Comment: It's pretty difficult to offer suggestions without knowing how the menu is implemented.

Comment: For sure, its a company website with logins so its a challenge. I added an edit to the original post with a snip of the menu bar in question. Also includes a reference below that. Possibly that helps? Even if you have any thoughts on the correct method I would be most grateful.

Comment: You could try getting the parent div, and from there reference the first row in the first table under that - click that row.

Answer (score 0):

My answer was to disregard "Clicking" through the menu and to just export the table I was needing instead. Hopefully that gives someone else an idea if they are stuck like I was.

Thank you for the assistance.